# What does it mean when a key is of a specific length in bits?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, bit

I'm learning some basic cryptography related programming and I'm now learning diffie-hellman-merkle key exchange. I was watching a [video by Computerphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yjrfm_oRO0w) where they explain the mathematics of it.

In the video, they said that you should use **n** that is 2000 or 4000 bits long. I've seen this key length be discussed as bits in several other places, like with AES. But I don't understand what "length in bits" means. What does it mean to have a key that is 2000 bits long, so if I need to write a program that creates or uses keys that are of certain length, what would I need to do?

Comment: Think of a 4-digit PIN. Each digit has a value between 0 and 9. So, a 4-digit pin can be any number between 0000 to 9999. That is, there are 10^4 = 10000 possible values for that PIN. Now, a computer represents numbers using bits (ones and zeros). If a key has 2000 bits, it means that it can be any value between 00000…0 to 11111…1 (any conbination of 0s and 1s of length 2000). There are [2^2000 possible values](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E2000)  for this key. Look up "binary number representation" for more information.

Comment: *"if I need to write a program that creates or uses keys that are of certain length, what would I need to do?"* That depends on the specific algorithm. AES supports keys of specific lengths that can be fully random. Most asymmetric algorithms like RSA cannot be random, because the key itself needs to adhere to some specific mathematical structure (number with specific properties which can be encoded into bytes/bits).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to write a program that creates keys of a certain length, you pass the desired key length to the program. You need to know in which unit the length is expressed (for example, some interfaces might require bytes rather than bits), but you usually don't need to know what the key length means under the hood.

The concrete meaning of the key length depends on the cryptographic scheme, and for some schemes, there can be an ambiguity as to what the “key length” is. It's typically one of three things:

- The length of a string that is associated with the algorithm, such as a key.
- A number n such that an integer parameter of the algorithm is picked between 2^(n-1) and (2^n)-1.
- A number n such that an integer parameter of the algorithm is picked between 1 (or some other small bound) and (2^n)-1.

Both of the last two cases are called “n-bit numbers”. In cryptography, “n-bit number” sometimes means a number that can be written with n digits in base 2, and sometimes a number which requires exactly n digits in base 2. In other words, “n-bit number” sometimes means a number whose bit-size is exactly n, and sometimes a number whose bit-size is at most n. You have to check the exact requirement in the description of each cryptographic scheme.

Depending on the cryptographic scheme, a different number is conventionally chosen as the “key length”. For any specific scheme, a larger key length is harder to break, but you can't compare key lengths between different schemes.

For most symmetric schemes, the key is a randomly generated string (each bit of the string has an independent ½ chance of being 0 or 1), and the length is the number of bits of the string. For example, AES-128 is AES using a 128-bit (16-byte) key. There is only one exception worth mentioning: [DES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard) keys are expressed as 64-bit strings, but only 56 of those bits are random (the other 8 are calculated from the random 56), and so DES is sometimes considered to have a “56-bit” key length and sometimes a “64-bit” key length.

For [Diffie-Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange#Cryptographic_explanation), the key length *n* is the exact size of the group (conventionally written *p*). Both the private key and the public key are numbers between 1 and *p*, so they're at-most *n*-bit numbers. This is as simple as it goes in terms of key length for asymmetric cryptography.

For [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Key_generation), the key length *n* is the exact size of the modulus, which is one part of the public key (the public key is a pair of numbers: the modulus and the public exponent). For example, 4096-bit RSA means that the modulus is between 2^4095 and 2^4096-1. The private key is also an *n*-bit number, but in the at-most sense.

For [DSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Signature_Algorithm), there are two numbers that can be called the key length, because the private key and the public key are chosen in intervals that have different sizes. The *public* key length is the size of the larger prime *p*; the public key is a number between 2 and *p*-2. The *private* key length is the size of the smaller prime *q*; the private key is a number between 1 and *q*-1.

For [elliptic curve cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic-curve_cryptography), the domain parameters of the algorithm are called a *curve*: a set of points, and a [parametrization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametrization_(geometry)) of this set of points. A private key is a parameter value that designates a point on the curve, and a public key is a pair of integers that are the coordinates of a point on the curve. In general, since the private key and the public key live in different mathematical spaces, there are two numbers that could be called the “key size”. A private key is a number between 1 and *n*-1 for some *m*-bit number *n*, and a public key is a point with two coordinates, each of which are between 0 and *q* for some *ℓ*-bit number *q*. In general, *m* and *ℓ* don't have to be equal. However, *n* and *q* are usually close (if they aren't, it's a waste of performance for a given security level), and so *m* and *ℓ* are usually equal and can be called the “key length” without ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

Every bit can be either 1 or 0. It's the basic unit in the digital world. As you may know, all that is digital end up being either 1 or 0. Each 1 and 0 is a bit.

So something of length `n bits` means that it has `n` 1s and 0s.